# Android studio mediaplayer auto reset after play

Tags: java, android-studio, media-player

New to Android Studio and android programming, I have looked here and the rest of the web but not been able to find a solution.

I am using viewflipper to create a slide show with next and previous buttons, this works just as it should. With each new image the user can touch the screen and get a short audio playback about image. There are 32 images for the first 15 all works well but after that the audio playback part stops working. 
Is there a way to set mediaplayer to play all 32 if required or does the media player have to be reset after each playback.
I am using an onclick method to play the sound, I do not want to place more buttons on the screen to reset the player, also if the user touches the screen after the initial playing of the audio then the audio will play again.

Is what I am trying to do possible

Comment: Please post relevant code, preferably as an MVCE; this might be an implementation issue. Can't you simply reconnect to the media player? I presume you can only use a limited number of channels at the same time.

Comment: save last played position in shared pref .. then play from last played position